# Operator Overloading not working even when both postfix and assignment are overloaded

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator, postfix-operator

This is the class definition

```
template <typename key_type, typename mapped_type>
class mymap {
    public:
    node<key_type, mapped_type> *root;

    /* Utility Functions */
    int height(node<key_type, mapped_type> *);
    int getBalance(node<key_type, mapped_type> *);

    node<key_type, mapped_type> *newNode(key_type, mapped_type);
    node<key_type, mapped_type> *rightRotate(node<key_type, mapped_type> *);
    node<key_type, mapped_type> *leftRotate(node<key_type, mapped_type> *);
    node<key_type, mapped_type> *insert_node(node<key_type, mapped_type> *, key_type, mapped_type);
    node<key_type, mapped_type> *minValueNode(node<key_type, mapped_type> *);
    node<key_type, mapped_type> *deleteNode(node<key_type, mapped_type> *, key_type);

    void insert(key_type, mapped_type);

    // Constructor
    mymap()
    {
    root = NULL;
    }


    class iterator {
        public:

        node<key_type,mapped_type> *ptr;

        iterator(){
            ptr = NULL;
        }
        /*void iterator(iterator &x) {
            ptr = x.ptr;

        }*/

        void operator++(int) {                
            ptr = increment(ptr); 
        }

        void operator=(const iterator &it) {
            ptr = it.ptr;
        //return (*this);
        }


        /*void  operator--(int) {
            ptr = decrement(ptr); 
        }*/

        void operator++() {
            ptr = increment(ptr); 
        }

        /*
        node <key_type,mapped_type>* operator--() {
            return *(decrement(ptr));
        }

        bool operator !=(iterator itr) {
            return (ptr != itr.ptr);
        }


        bool operator ==(iterator itr) {
            return (ptr == itr.ptr);
        }
        */  
    };

    iterator begin() {

        iterator it ;
        node<key_type,mapped_type> * tmp = root;

        while (tmp->left != NULL)
            tmp = tmp->left;    

        it.ptr = tmp;
        return it;
    }

    iterator end() {
        iterator it;
        it.ptr = NULL;
        return it;
    }

};
```

In main this code won't compile and gives error at line 10. Maybe because I'm trying to do something wrong while overloading postfix++ and assignment operators.

```
mymap<int, int> A;

A.insert(1, 5);
A.insert(2, 5);
A.insert(3, 5);
A.insert(4, 5);

mymap<int,int> :: iterator it = A.begin();
mymap<int,int> :: iterator it1 = A.end();
it1 = it++;
```

Plz help :(. This is an AVL implementation of map I'm trying to accomplish.
This is the link to the complete map file if this is necessary.
https://www.box.com/s/oom4bjnve9zmlpdcevip

Comment: What is the error that the compiler gives?

Comment: You should learn about constructor initializer lists, preferably before embarking on a bigger design such as the present one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong return types.  Neither prefix nor postfix operators return `void`.  Prefix should return an `iterator &` and postfix should return a `iterator` instance.

For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/f6s9k9ta%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
it1 = it++;
```

This will evaluate the postincrement of your iterator, and use the return type (in your declaration is `void`) to initialize `it1`, which is a compiler error. Note that, when overloading operators you should *do as `int`s do*. I.e. Try to mimic the behavior of the operators in existing types to avoid confusion. That includes having `operator=` returning a reference to the object that has been assigned.